# JavaScript: Model View Controller (MVC) refactoring existing code strategy

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, revealing-prototype

I am about to re-factor a large single page web app with a Python/Django backend.  I do not want to use any of the existing frameworks such as Angular.js, JavaScriptMVC, BackBone.js, etc. There is already a huge amount of HTML and JavaScript code in place and it will take way to long to conform to their methodology.

I have developed an MVC architecture using the revealing prototype pattern.  You can see a simplified working demo and the source code here: http://jsbin.com/yilad/33/edit.  There are some _vars that are intended to be public vars I just did not have time to rename them all, so please ignore the underscore connotations.

My MVC is: [model]<----->[controller]<------>[view]

The architecture in the example achieves everything I am looking for:

1. A class like object (FolderManager) that may utilize it's own model class like object, view class like object, and controller class like object.
2. Each FolderManager has private, internal public, and public members.
3. The model, view, and controller only have access to the parts that the main class decides they need.
4. The FolderManager automatically instantiates it's model view and controller.
5. The FolderManager can have multiple models, views, and controllers.
6. This architecture allows me to easily copy/paste my existing spaghetti code into the new format.

WHAT I DON'T LIKE and need some help with:

1. The constructor function for the FolderManager uses a some trickery to achieve the internal public members.

   - Is there another / better way to achieve this? (probably through inheritance)
   - A way to implement it automatically: ie var FolderManager = Class({}).

     - http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/create-an-object-oriented-javascript-class-constructor.html#fbid=j_hWP0EDjFn
     - I tried adapting the technique above to pick up my public_vars and internal_vars and apply them to the constructor. I have not been able to get it to work where self would be available to the constructor at instantiation so that i can pass it to the model, view, and controller. (this would solve the problem, look for the code below)

       `//create public vars (move this to a Class Method)
       for (var v in public_vars){this[v] = public_vars[v];}
       //create internal vars (move this to a Class Method)
       var self = {};
       for (v in public_vars){self[v] = public_vars[v];}
       for (v in internal_vars){self[v] = internal_vars[v];}`
2. I am instantiating the model, view, and controller inside the constructor which works and i like the simplicity of the code but, this is the cause of item 1 above.  I am having trouble understanding / implementing a way to extend the classes.  Any suggestions to rework this strategy are appreciated.

The Main Class constructor:

```
var FolderManager = function(name){
    //self instantiate
    if (!(this instanceof FolderManager)) return new FolderManager(name);

    //private vars
    var privateVar = 'private vars are available only to the \"'+name+'\" constructor.';

    //internal public vars
    var internal_vars={
        internalVar:'internal_vars are available only to internal classes.',
        sortable:false
    };
    //public vars
    var public_vars = {
        publicVar:'public_vars are available to everything.',
        toString:name,
        name:name
    };

    //create public vars (move this to a Class Method)
    for (var v in public_vars){this[v] = public_vars[v];}
    //create internal vars (move this to a Class Method)
    var self = {};
    for (v in public_vars){self[v] = public_vars[v];}
    for (v in internal_vars){self[v] = internal_vars[v];}

    //instantiate private classes with internalally public vars
    //and the classes they each need to have access to
    var model = new FolderManagerModel(self);
    var view = new FolderManagerView(self, model);
    var cont = new FolderManagerCont(self, model, view);

    //provide public access to internal classes as required
    this.refresh = model.refresh.bind(model)
    this.out = view.out.bind(view)

    // init model
    this.refresh();
};
```

The Model Constructor & prototype (view and controller user the same format, see the demo for the full code):

```
function FolderManagerModel(self){
    // model
    this.self = self;
    this.name = self.name+'.model';
    this._folders = null; //folder objects
    this._sorting = 'none'; //current sorting
    this._loading = new ObjectEvent(this);

}
FolderManagerModel.prototype = function(){
    function refresh(options){
        //process options and make simulated ajax call to local data
        if (!options) options = {};
        this._loading.notify({ status : true });
        if (options.add){
             this._folders.push(options.add);
        }
        this._sorting = options.sort === undefined ? 'none' : options.sort || this._sorting;
        var data = this._folders || {objects: [
            {name: 'folder 3'},
            {name: 'folder 2'},
            {name: 'folder 4'},
            {name: 'folder 1'}
        ]};
        var objects = data.objects || data;
        success.call(this, objects);
        //end simulated ajax call

    }
    function success(objects){
        //store the data locally
        this._folders = objects.slice(0);
        //sort after local folders are updated
        var sorted = this._sorting == 'alpha' ? sortApha.call(this, objects.slice(0)) : objects;
        this._loading.notify({ status : false, data:sorted});
    }
    //public members
    return {
        refresh:refresh
    };
}();
```

---

### UPDATE:

I have completed my Class constructor to eliminate some of the leg work and I fixed my internal public variable issues.  The one question i have left is: in-order for the debugger to show the class name for the object i needed to create a function named for the class. The only way to do this was to use a new function() constructor.  I understand it is not good practice due to performance issues since the function needs to be parsed each time it is called.  However, since i am using it in a constructor function, this will only be called on instantiation (once).  Is this still a  bad idea or is this one of those cases where it is appropriate?

Class constructor:

```
var Class = function (className, methods, options) {

    options = options || {};
    options.ret = options.ret !== false;
    options.context = options.context || window

    //compile the constructor & internalMembers
    var init = function () {
        console.log('Class() is building:', this.constructor.name);
        //provide inernal object for constructor
        this.internal = {}
        this.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
        //remove internal from public scope
        var int = this.internal
        delete this.internal
        //populate self with this and internal vars
        var self = {pub:this, int:{}};
        for (var v in int){
            self.int[v] = int[v];
        }
        // Instantiate internalMembers with self
        var internalClass = methods.internalClass;
        if (internalClass) internalClass.call(this, self);
    };

    //create constructor function with className (fixes class name in debugger)
    //also includes self instantiation
    var klass = new Function("init", "return function " + className + "(name){ if (!(this instanceof " + className + ")) return new " + className + "(name);init.apply(this,arguments) };")(init);

    //create prototype from Class method
    var prototype = methods.prototype;
    if (prototype) klass.prototype = new prototype();

    //add other Class methods to prototype
    var exclude = ['internalClass', 'initialize', 'prototype'];
    for (var property in methods) {
        if (exclude.indexOf(property) == -1) {
            klass.prototype[property] = methods[property];
        }
    }

    if (options.ret) return klass; //return the class
    else options.context[className] = klass; //create the class
};
```

And it's use like this:

```
Class('FolderManager', {

    constructor: function FolderManager(name) {

        //private vars
        var privateVar = 'this value is only accesable to the \"'+name+'\" constructor.';

        //public internal mthods and vars
        this.internal.internalVar='this value is only accesable to internal classes.',
        this.internal.sortable=false;

        //public vars
        this.publicVar='this is a public vlue';
        this.name = name;
    },
    internalClass:function(self){

       //instantiate private classes
        var model = new FolderManagerModel(self);
        var view = new FolderManagerView(self, model);
        var cont = new FolderManagerCont(self, model, view);

        //public access private class methods
        this.refresh = model.refresh.bind(model);
        this.out = view.out.bind(view);
        this.model = model;

        // init model
        this.refresh();
    },
    prototype:function(){

        // all static vars and methods here
    },
},{ret:false,context:this});
```

Full working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/arctelix/8cS4a/

Comment: Please put the relevant parts of the code (maybe with shortened values) in your question.

Comment: I don't see why "Main" should have any private or public vars at all. Just putting them on the model should be fine…

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Bergi. The addition of main was the solution to javascripts lack of private and internal members.  I come from an action script/ java background.  Since the app will have many components this strategy will keep the global scope as unpoluted as possible.  I have never seen this done before and wonder if I am making a mistake.  Do you se any disadvantage to this strategy?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with having a `Main` for the App around, but it shouldn't need to have to have much state and properties.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks again.  Please look at the update above and let me know what you think of the Class constructor.

Comment: The function will only be parsed every time a new Class is created, not every time a constructor is called - so yes, it's fine. And if you really had problems with this, you could easily remove the named function thing for production.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you slightly over-engineer all this.

While ago I've created [SPA micro-framework](https://github.com/c-smile/spapp) with views, controllers, routes and scopes. Check it, it just 75 lines of code.

Comment: SPA looks very cool.  However, as i said i have not sought out to crate a frame work and can not use any existing framework.  The code base i am working with already has it's own route methodology in place and is extremely complex. All the controllers are set up and the HTML is defined.  I just needed to plug all the JavaScript into an MVC.  This provides a blank canvas where i can just copy and paste all the methods and variables.  I do appreciate your taking the time to look.

Comment: For small task more comfortable use separate logic in different files.  Including file via ajax inside main file

Answer (score 0):

Is also simple realiation MVC

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="">
 </div>
  <script src="main/views/view.js" async></script>
  <script src="main/models/model.js" async></script>
  <script src="main/controllers/action.js" async></script>
  <script src="main/main.js" async></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS files:

View:

```
var view = {
 showNumber: function (n) {
    $("input#res").val(n);
 }
};
```

Model:

```
var model = {
 calculate: function () {
    var x  = $("input#input").val();
    return x * 2;
 }
};
```

Controller:

```
var controller = {
  action: function () {
    $("button#showResult").click(function () {
        var res = model.calculate();
        view.showNumber(res);
    });
  }
};
```